# URL Rewriting for url with countrycode

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am writing a multi language website. Therefore I would like some help with a URL rewrite problem.

**Case:**

- When someone visits www.example.com without adding a country code (nl, en, de) the htaccess redirects the visitor to www.example.com/nl/ **i.g.**
  `RewriteRule !(nl|en|de)(.*).*   /nl/ [R=301,L]`
- The website is renewed and has got many url's directing to the website (google, forums). i.g. www.example.com/oldpage-nomore.html. What I would like is the following; the htaccess should detect that the request uri doesn't contain nl,en or de and should redirect to pagenotfound.php. `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html /public/oldurl?section=nl&notfound=$1$2&basehref=true&%1 [PT,L]` the problem with this Rewrite rule is: all files ending in .html are being redirected.

What I am looking for is the following:

- When someone visits www.example.com and no request uri is entered this should redirect to www.example.com/nl/
- When there is a requested uri and this doens't contain a countrycode (nl|en|de) than redirect to pagenotfound.php

I tried the following but it doens't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(nl|en|de)$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)\.html$ /pagenotfound.php?page=$2 [L,R=404]
```

I hope someone can help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to place this .htaccess file at the server root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /nl/ [R]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(nl|en|de)
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)\.html$ /pagenotfound.php?page=$2 [L,R=404]
```

(you probably made several mistakes, I tried to fix them)
I'm not sure with the first RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} regular expression - maybe remove the question mark or slash, I don't now... can't test now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check this tonight and let you know.